# Is it common to run 20 python workers which uses Redis as Queue ?

Tags: python, redis, queue, worker

This program listen to Redis queue. If there is data in Redis, worker start to do their jobs. All these jobs have to run simultaneously that's why each worker listen to one particular Redis queue.

My question is : Is it common to run more than 20 workers to listen to Redis ?

python /usr/src/worker1.py
python /usr/src/worker2.py
python /usr/src/worker3.py
python /usr/src/worker4.py
python /usr/src/worker5.py
....
....
python /usr/src/worker6.py

Comment: This seems like an unanswerable question. Yes its possible and if it serves your purpose, do it. But is it common? Probably not.

Comment: @ChrisCharles well that's mosty what you get with celery (in this case using redis as broker but that's not the main point IMHO), and using tasks queues like celery is becoming rather common.

Comment: I suppose it also depends on how you define common. Of all python processes running in the world, most aren't run like that :)

Answer (score 2):

Having multiple worker processes (and when I mean "multiple" I'm talking hundreds or more), possibly running on different machines, fetching jobs from a job queue is indeed a common pattern nowadays. There even are whole packages/frameworks devoted to such workflows, like for example Celery.

What is less common is trying to write the whole task queues system from scratch in a seemingly ad-hoc way instead of using a dedicated task queues system like Celery, ZeroMQ or something similar.

Answer (score 1):

If your worker need to do a long task with data, it's a solution. but each data must be treated by a single worker.

By this way, you can easly (without thread,etc..)  distribute your tasks, it's better if your worker doesn't work in the same server